# Java 8 - customised sort based on specific order

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I would like to sort the user list based on their status but the order must be based on the order that I set.

I want to set the order of list,

The order should be **1, 0 , 5**. We should also keep in mind to order the username as well.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList();
         users.add(new User("A", 1));
         users.add(new User("B", 5));
         users.add(new User("C", 0));
         users.add(new User("D", 1));
         users.add(new User("E", 5));
         users.add(new User("F", 0));
```

**Here's the user class**

```
public class User {
         private String username;
         private Integer status;
     }
```

It should look like this

```
[
    {
      "username": "A",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
       "username": "D",
       "status": 1
    },
    {
       "username": "C",
       "status": 0
    },
    {
       "username": "F",
       "status": 0
    },
    {
       "username": "B",
       "status": 5
    },
    {
       "username": "E",
       "status": 5
    }
]
```

I not sure if it's possible to use **Comparator.comparing**, since this one is neither ascending nor descending order.

Comment: Yes, `Comparator` can deal with, it just needs to return +1/-1/0 based on the comparison of the two values supplied.  Best bet is to just give it a try

Comment: if 1,0,5 is the only status numbers, then you can easily order it using comparator.

Comment: Yes, you can write your custom comparator using the desired logic. But, I hope, you know that's a weird sorting requirement without any additional information of *why* attached to it though.

Comment: Subtract 1, then square.   1,0,5 -> 0, 1, 16 ... which is easy to sort

Comment: @MadProgrammer what is -1, 0, and 1 ?
1 = true
0 = false
-1 is ? sorry, i'm still not familiar with the comparator

Comment: @KennethC `Compator` just returns a negative or positive or zero value based on the result of the comparison and the order you want the values to be sorted

Comment: @KennethC Take a look at the documentation of [`Comparator.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) to see what the different return values mean (negative means less than, zero means equal to, positive means greater than).

Comment: If its allowed to modify the structure of `User class` than just add one more attribute say `Integer rank;` and you can define the rank based on your ordering of status attribute like say `users.add(new User("A", 1,0));` here status 1 is sortest in order and its rank=0. And then you can use Comparator on `rank`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One approach could be to hold a list with the order you want and sort the users according to its index:

```
final List<Integer> order = Arrays.asList(1, 0, 5);
users.sort(
    Comparator.comparing((User u) -> order.indexOf(u.getStatus()))
              .thenComparing(User::getUsername));
```

Note that while this approach should be reasonable for a small number of statuses (like you currently have), it may slow down sorting if there are a large number of statuses and you need to do perform an O(n) search each time. A better performing approach (albeit arguably not as sleek), would be to use a map:

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();
order.put(1, 0);
order.put(0, 1);
order.put(5 ,2);
users.sort(Comparator.comparing((User u) -> order.get(u.getStatus()))
                     .thenComparing(User::getUsername));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind using Guava in your project, you can use `Ordering.explicit`:

```
users.sort(Ordering.explicit(1, 0, 5).onResultOf(User::getStatus));
```

If you want to sort by name also, then add `thenComparing`:

```
users.sort(Ordering
        .explicit(1, 0, 5)
        .onResultOf(User::getStatus)
        .thenComparing(User::getUsername));
```

Comment: this is how I would do it, mainly because that `explicit` is well such a clear and "explicit" name

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `1`, `0`, and `5` will be the only values of `status`, AJNeufeld made an excellent point in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255793/java-8-customised-sort-based-on-specific-order/53255936#comment93396197_53255793); they stated that you can use an equation to map each value into an ascending order. In this case, the equation would be `(x - 1)^2` where `x` is the value of `status`:

```
users.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(user -> Math.pow(user.getStatus() - 1, 2)));
```

If you were to print the contents of `user` after calling the above snippet, you'd get:

> [User [username=A, status=1], User [username=D, status=1], User [username=C, status=0], User [username=F, status=0], User [username=B, status=5], User [username=E, status=5]]

Comment: Why not just |x - 1|?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov `v^1`…

Comment: @Holger Excuse me?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov `value ^ 1` is even simpler than `Math.abs(value - 1)` (the difference is not as big as the difference of both to `Math.pow`, though).

Comment: @Holger `0^1 < 1^1` (should be greater)

Comment: @Holger Forget it. `^` is XOR. I thought you are talking about the power.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov you can simply remove the wrong comment…

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this step by step

```
//order define here
List<Integer> statusOrder= Arrays.asList(1,0,5,2);

//define sort by status
Comparator<User> byStatus = (u1, u2) -> {
    return Integer.compare(statusOrder.indexOf(u1.getStatus()), statusOrder.indexOf(u2.getStatus()));
};

//define sort by name
Comparator<User> byName = Comparator.comparing(User::getUsername);

//actualy sort
users.sort(byStatus.thenComparing(byName));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you need custom ordering and that means you need to define somewhere that ordering either in HashMap<**Status,Rank**>> or one simple way add one more attribute say **Integer rank;** and you can define the rank based on your ordering for status attribute like say users.add(new User("A", 1,0)); here status 1 is sortest in order and its rank=0. And then you can use *Comparator on rank attribute*.

For e.g :

```
public class User {
    public String username;
    public Integer status;
    public Integer rank;

    public User(String username, Integer status, Integer rank) 
    { 
        this.username = username; 
        this.status = status; 
        this.rank = rank;
    } 
}
```

**Comparator class :**

```
class SortByRank implements Comparator<User> 
{ 
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of 
    // rank number 
    public int compare(User a, User b) 
    { 
        return a.rank - b.rank; 
    } 
}
```

**Main Class :**

```
class Main 
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 
         List<User> users = new ArrayList();
         users.add(new User("A", 1, 0));
         users.add(new User("B", 5, 2));
         users.add(new User("C", 0, 1));
         users.add(new User("D", 1, 0));
         users.add(new User("E", 5, 2));
         users.add(new User("F", 0, 1));

        System.out.println("Unsorted"); 
        for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) 
            System.out.print(users.get(i).username); 

        Collections.sort(users, new SortByRank()); 

        System.out.println("\nSorted by Rank"); 
        for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) 
            System.out.print(users.get(i).username); 
    } 
}
```